# how to eliminate the render blocking in angular-cli site?

Tags: javascript, angular

after running `ng build --prod` I can go into my `index.html` file in the newly created dist folder and add the `async` attribute to the bundled script tags to keep them from being blocking. this helps with website speed but sporadically crashes the site. is there an option in the `angular-cli.json` that would add this for me during the build in a better way?
i ran my site through google's test my website and the only thing i have left to fix is Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and [css](/questions/tagged/css) in above-the-fold content

below is a the more specific result i get from https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content

Your page has 4 blocking script resources and 1 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page. None of the above-the-fold content on your page could be rendered without waiting for the following resources to load. Try to defer or asynchronously load blocking resources, or inline the critical portions of those resources directly in the [html](/questions/tagged/html). Remove render-blocking JavaScript:

Comment: @arvil please provide the answer

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid its not possible with the CLI as of now. See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3323 for a discussion on the topic.

Comment: correct, its not added in the CLI as of now. What i've done myself is adding the async attribute to only the first script element occurrence. This works good and satisfies the pagespeed. I was thinking of making a lit nodejs script that i can run after the ng build process in order to automate it.

Comment: can u please elaborate it..and provide some sample code it will be useful for me..please becaz I'm going nuts to solve this

Comment: Agreed, if you've got an example of this that would be great.

Comment: @DARKGuy No workaround needed if you use CLI 8.2. The scripts are added to index.html with the defer attribute. In case of a “modern” build, script are added with type="module" which are deferred by default.

Comment: As of version 8.2.0, defer attributes are automatically added to classic scripts (module scripts are deferred by default). https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3323#issuecomment-530374329