# Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I can go into my index.html file in the newly created dist folder and add the async attribute to the bundled script tags to keep them from being blocking. this helps with website speed but sporadically crashes the site. is there an option in the angular-cli.json that would add this for me during the build in a better way? i ran my site through google's test my website and the only thing i have left to fix is Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and css in above-the-fold content

below is a the more specific result i get from https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content

Your page has 4 blocking script resources and 1 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page. None of the above-the-fold content on your page could be rendered without waiting f[image]or the following resources to load.

Comment: My guess is that you have a Single Page Application in Angular 2. So the question is - what content would be displayed without the Javascript? With a normal SPA the whole rendering, and fetching of content is done through the Javascript. So naturally it will be render-blocking.

Comment: but my site score is getting low. i need to improve my score as well

Comment: i need to eliminate render block issue on those js file in my dist folder.please help me

Comment: So what content is it that you want to display before the JS is loaded? If you have an angular single page app, then Angular is handling the content and templating, so obviously all rendering will be blocked until it loads Angular. 

If you want to avoid any JS to block your render. Then let the server create and render the content. But that is obviously not what you want if you choose Angular.

Comment: I can't get u properly

Comment: @ArvindAudacious what Marcus is suggesting is that you use Server-Side Rendering (http://openmymind.net/2012/5/30/Client-Side-vs-Server-Side-Rendering/) in your Angular app, which enables the page to be (surprise!) rendered by the server, rather than dynamically created on the client-side by your JS.

Angular enables this with Angular Universal (https://universal.angular.io/). It doesn't take too much extra code to add SSR to your app, and there are additional benefits in terms of being able to optimize your website for search engines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to eliminate the render blocking in angular-cli site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44234700/how-to-eliminate-the-render-blocking-in-angular-cli-site)